# Perl cannot install Catalyst dependency

Tags: perl, catalyst

I'm getting the following error from Perl. Am I doing something wrong or should I report it?

> Can't locate object method "_process_isa_option" via package
>   "Class::MOP::Attribute" at
>   /home/martin3/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/Moose/Meta/Attribute.pm
>   line 207.

This is in trying to (re)install Catalyst::Runtime using cpanm.

My code used to be working, but Perl was upgraded and I am trying to get it working again.

Comment: As it happened, the specific code that failed was only used in a test, so I installed Catalyst::Runtime using cpanm --notest and then installed any remaining dependencies (with the CPAN tests), so my site is working again.

Answer (score 2):

[This bug report](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?ShowHeaders=1;id=92780) shows what the problem is. Looks like you've updated some of your dependencies from the Moose::* namespace, but not all of them.

If you run `moose-outdated` on your command line, then it will tell you which modules you need to update.

Comment: ~/perl5/bin/moose-outdated  does not give any result.